# Reset Django migrations: relation "django_migrations" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I somehow screwed up my migrations when creating the database for a new project. I now have the problem of migrations that don't apply:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: wagtailusers, wagtailembeds, wagtailadmin, sessions, admin, wagtailcore, auth, contenttypes, wagtaildocs, taggit, wagtailsearch, home, wagtailforms, wagtailredirects, wagtailimages
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253399/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-1-7) (and a few others), it seems like my best bet is to clear stuff out of the `django_migrations` table. So I ran:

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='wagtailusers';
```

and got the error:

```
ERROR:  relation "django_migrations" does not exist
```

How can django_migrations not exist? What am I doing wrong? I basically want to scrub everything in the database and all the migrations and start over from scratch, but it's apparently far more complicated than I suspected. (Is there a simpler way to basically start over with the database and migrations?)

**EDIT:**

I tried reverting one app and migrating it forward again.

I ran `./manage.py showmigrations wagtailusers`, which showed all migrations applied:

```
wagtailusers
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_verbose_name_on_userprofile
 [X] 0003_add_verbose_names
 [X] 0004_capitalizeverbose
```

I then unapplied all of the migrations with `./manage.py migrate wagtailusers zero`:

```
Operations to perform:
  Unapply all migrations: wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Unapplying wagtailusers.0004_capitalizeverbose... OK
  Unapplying wagtailusers.0003_add_verbose_names... OK
  Unapplying wagtailusers.0002_add_verbose_name_on_userprofile... OK
  Unapplying wagtailusers.0001_initial... OK
```

`showmigrations` then shows them all unapplied. So I then reapply the migrations with `./manage.py migrate wagtailusers`:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying wagtailusers.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0002_add_verbose_name_on_userprofile... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0003_add_verbose_names... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0004_capitalizeverbose... OK
```

Everything is checked in `showmigrations`. But when I run migrate again, it still seems to think there's something missing?

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Comment: Such questions are a bit difficult to answer because we don exactly know what may have gone wrong somewhere. If it is a development machine you can always drop the entire schema.

Comment: The problem is that I also don't know what's gone wrong.

Comment: If you don't have anything in the DB that you care about, just drop the DB and re-create it. Assuming this is postgres a `dropdb databasename && createdb -O django_user -T template0 -E UTF-8 databasename` should get you back to being able to say `manage.py migrate`

Comment: I thought that fixed my problem, but it appears to have done the same thing as `./manage.py reset_db`. I reran `./manage.py migrate` and it applied the migrations that got it up to the same point as before. So I'm right back where I started with this question.

Comment: Have you done makemigrations? what is your Django version?

Comment: `makemigrations` says "No changes detected". Django version is 1.9.5.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, I think it's just the output is confusing?
Your steps appeared to be

- Run `manage.py migrate` which worked
- Run `manage.py migrate wagtailusers zero` which also worked
- Run `manage.py migrate wagtailusers` which worked
- Run `manage.py migrate` which says `No migrations to apply`

If that's the exact order of events and I've understood things correctly, then yes that's actually what you want manage.py to say. It takes the migration engine a bit to see if there are any migrations, and it has to calculate a decent amount of state so it can determine if there are migrations that should be created but aren't there. If you want to double check this then `manage.py showmigrations` should show all your existing migrations with an `[x]` in front of them, thus showing them as having been applied.

Hopefully I've understood your question correctly.