# makemigrations not detecting changes after moving models to a modelsdirectory

Tags: python, django

My old structure used to be like this:

```
models.py
    class Model1
    class Model2
    ...
```

I have since moved this to

```
modelsdir
   __init__.py
   model1.py
      class Model1
   model2.py
      class Model2
models.py
   from modelsdir.model1 import Model1
   from modelsdir.model2 import Model2
```

After this change, `makemigraitons` and `makemigrations myapp` no longer detect any changes done on the models. Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:

I have since moved to this: removed models.py and renamed modelsdir to models

now it looks like so:

```
models
    __init__.py
        from .model1 import Model1
        from .model2 import Model2
    model1.py
    model2.py
```

Unfortunately this still doesn't detect any changes.

Comment: Add `modelsdir` to `installed apps` in `settings.py`. Rename those `modelsx.py` file back to models.py. If you don't want to have more than one Model class in a file just create another app for it. Make your life easy.

Comment: @Tushortz would having one model class per app even be feasible? That sounds pretty bad considering one app can have well over a dozen models. This approach would mean creating a dozen applications.

Comment: Why do you want to store each model in a separate file? Why not stay with `models.py`?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat That's why its better to just have related models in a single model file.

Comment: @a_guest the file was getting pretty large, there were suggestions to split models.py into multiple files but seems like this approach's bringing more problems than it solves.

Comment: With a proper IDE you shouldn't be at trouble with large files. But if you wish to stick with multiple modules what about _defining_ your models in a separate module each and then _importing_ those models in `models.py`? `models.py` would just contain an `import` statement for each model then. Or is this what you did already? Cause that should actually work.

Comment: @a_guest this is already what I have. The problem is that makemigrations isn't detecting any of my changes.

Comment: you should reset the migrations try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253399/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-1-7?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat What version of Django and Python do you use? I just tried moving the models to a separate module within a sample project and it worked. I used Django 1.11 and Python 2.7. Maybe [setting an app label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) helps in your case. By the way how does your `INSTALLED_APPS` look like?

Comment: @a_guest I'm using 1.9 on 2.7 because of some celery integrations. Hmm maybe something's wrong with my migrations

Comment: @a_guest INSTALLED_APPS does have my app listed there, if that's what you're looking for:

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat Are you sure you're editing / importing the correct files? And that you don't override the model's names later on in `models.py`? This shouldn't be due to preceding migrations, those modules are still present in `models.py` as before, the only thing that changed is their `__module__` attribute but AFAIK this is not relevant to django; it goes by the `__name__`. Have you manually changed some parts of the existing migrations?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have a django project that is structured this way, and I had to add this in my `modelsdir/__init__.py` file:

```
from .model1 import *
from .model2 import *
```

I also didn't keep the original `models.py` file in my top-level app folder.

This is on Django 1.10/1.11 and Python 3.

Comment: I just did this, deleted models.py, renamed modelsdir to models and added the import statements all to the init file. Still doesn't detect any changes :(

Comment: And you're still sure the app is in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Also, try specifying the app name: `./manage.py makemigrations [appname]` without the braces.

Comment: yes I'm positive it's still in INSTALLED APPS, and yes I've already tried makemigrations myapp

Comment: Do you have these models set to `managed = False`? Also check if your models define an `app_label` in its `Meta` class, that it's the correct app name.

Comment: It might also be helpful to show what model changes you're expecting `makemigrations` to detect.