# Programming Error: "user_id of relation APP_MODEL does not exist"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've set User as a foreign key on my Video model. I am using the default django auth User model, and have managed to create a user using the serializer and view that I set up for it. The problem is that whenever I try to create a video entry I hit the title error.

I've tried clearing the database, redoing the migrations, but there aren't any migrations for the app that handles the user serializer.

The Model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Video(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    map_marker = models.ForeignKey(MapMarker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    ip_addr = models.TextField()
    file_id = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

Full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos/

Django Version: 2.2.1
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'userbase',
 'trickspot',
 'profanity']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (column "user_id" of relation "trickspot_video" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "trickspot_video" ("user_id", "map_marker_id", "...
                                       ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in view
  116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in create
  21.         self.perform_create(serializer)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in perform_create
  26.         serializer.save()

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in save
  214.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in create
  943.             instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  422.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1335.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\Zeph\.virtualenvs\SK8M8_API-LRdA6z3-\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /videos/
Exception Value: column "user_id" of relation "trickspot_video" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "trickspot_video" ("user_id", "map_marker_id", "...
                                       ^
```

The entry should be saved with the key of the user I selected on the API view.

Comment: Can you show the *full* traceback please?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem done

Comment: It looks like you did migrated the database completely. Did you make migrations, and run those migrations?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yup, ran it again just now to be sure. I've also deleted the migrations earlier and reran them.

Comment: `for the app that handles the user serializer` it's not about User, it's about Video model. `I've also deleted the migrations` careful with that: Django stores info about applied migrations in DB so removing files only is not clean/safe way. If you recreated all the migration files then, I reckon, you're having now `0001_initial` only which is marked as applied in the DB. Perhaps that's the case. You can try `DELETE FROM django_migrations` or recreate DB from the scratch (removing your data has no effect in your case).

Comment: @IvanStarostin I can't figure out the full delete from django_migrations line, would you help me out please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253399/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-1-7

Comment: @IvanStarostin I tried doing it but now more stuff has broken. I've flushed the database a bunch of times already now and that didn't help. After I've deleted migrations from the database, once I run manage.py migrate, is it supposed to say "no migrations to apply"?

Comment: Did you run makemigrations before that?

Comment: @IvanStarostin yep

Comment: @IvanStarostin I'm just going to go ahead and remake my database.

Comment: If you don't care about data - drop your DB and start from the scratch. Something is not true or completely broken here.

Answer (score 0):

Something got broken along the way and dropping the DB and starting again fixed the problem.

Thanks