# Django: Broken migration => remove old migration files

Tags: django, django-migrations

I was trying to remove on my dev machine old migration files with

```
manage.py myapp zero
```

But it failed at some point and I messed up. I have a project with ~1000 migration files.
Unfortunately I have no backups for my dev sql database. (I have to build everything from scretch)

But on my prodiction system I have also this ~1000 migration files and was wondering if it is possible to delete all migration files and just use the last state. So that each
migrations folder has only one migration file left.

Is this possible? This would save my life ...

EDIT:
I ended up using this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing

Comment: You can delete the migrations in your local app, then send to the server. This will remove the migration files. Pay attention and test on your machine the "makemigrations" may occur inconsistencies between the databases (local/server). Save migration files to have a backup in case something goes wrong. I don't know if this is the best practice

Comment: Take a look at squashing migrations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset migrations in Django 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253399/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-1-7)