Django test suite throws error on field that doesn't exist in latest migrations
The following simple test,
from django.test import TestCase
    
    class TestSetup(TestCase):   
        def test_setUp(self):
            pdb.set_trace()
            # Code here deleted, it made no difference to the error.

throws the errors:
> Destroying old test database for alias 'default'... Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
> line 1957, in get_prep_value
>     return float(value) ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in
> <module>
>     main()   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 442, in execute_from_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 436, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py",
> line 24, in run_from_argv
>     super().run_from_argv(argv)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 412, in run_from_argv
>     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 458, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py",
> line 68, in handle
>     failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py",
> line 1054, in run_tests
>     old_config = self.setup_databases(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py",
> line 950, in setup_databases
>     return _setup_databases(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/utils.py",
> line 221, in setup_databases
>     connection.creation.create_test_db(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py",
> line 78, in create_test_db
>     call_command(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 194, in call_command
>     return command.execute(*args, **defaults)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 458, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 106, in wrapper
>     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
> line 356, in handle
>     post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 135, in migrate
>     state = self._migrate_all_forwards(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
>     state = self.apply_migration(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 252, in apply_migration
>     state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py",
> line 132, in apply
>     operation.database_forwards(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py",
> line 235, in database_forwards
>     schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 830, in alter_field
>     self._alter_field(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py",
> line 287, in _alter_field
>     super()._alter_field(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 1025, in _alter_field
>     new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 429, in effective_default
>     return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)   File
> "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
> line 954, in get_db_prep_save
>     return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)   File
> "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
> line 947, in get_db_prep_value
>     value = self.get_prep_value(value)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
> line 1959, in get_prep_value
>     raise e.__class__( ValueError: Field 'amount' expected a number but got ''.

The field 'amount' does exist, but in a model that isn't loaded for any tests:
models.py
    
class Appointment(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0.0)

But just in case it's instantiating that model in the process of creating the test database, I migrated "default=0.0" to "default='0.0' " (Single quotes around the value).  Same error.
I also tried deleting the postgresql test database manually with psql.
I'm initiating the test with
python manage.py test

and also by specifying the app_name:
python manage.py test giraffe

from the project directory.
Relevant migrations, in sequential order:
# Generated by Django 4.1.3 on 2023-01-10 22:58
from django.db import migrations, models   

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('giraffe', '0014_appointment_notes'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='appointment',
            name='amount',
            field=models.FloatField(blank=True, default=''),
        ),
    ]

and
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('giraffe', '0015_alter_appointment_amount'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='appointment',
            name='amount',
            field=models.FloatField(blank=True),
        ),
    ]

and
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('giraffe', '0016_alter_appointment_amount'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='appointment',
            name='amount',
            field=models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0.0),
        ),
    ]

And some earlier migrations pertaining to a model with an 'amount' field, but a model which was deleted, but still shows up in the test database.
...migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UnreimbursedMileage',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('mileage_rate_category', models.CharField(choices=[('FB22a', 'Federal Business Rate, Qtr. 1&2 2022'), ('FB22b', 'Federal Business Rate, Qtr. 3&4, 2022'), ('FB23', 'Federal Business Rate 2023')], default='FB22a', max_length=5)),
                ('num_miles', models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)),
                ('amount', models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('for_appointment', models.OneToOneField(editable=False, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='giraffe.appointment')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Unreimbursed Mileage',
            },
        ),

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('giraffe', '0054_rename_to_do_next_time_todonexttime_and_more'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='unreimbursedmileage',
            name='for_appointment',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Dummy',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='UnreimbursedMileage',
        ),
    ]


Please provide a [mre], start by sharing the complete error traceback. Also share any files / code written by you that shows up in the traceback.

Share the full traceback.

@AbdulAzizBarkat , traceback added.

Show us the relevant migration files of your app. And please format that traceback as a code block, it's difficult to read as a quote.

@AbdulAzizBarkat  There are seven migrations which might possibly apply.  I can include them above, but the very first 0001_inital mentions a model - with an 'amount' field - which no longer exists in later migrations.  But that model shows up in the test database.  How do I get test to use only the current db version?

Migrations are a versioning strategy for your database. Django applies them sequentially on your database (the problem would likely be in one of the recent migrations)

@AbdulAzizBarkat  I've included the last migrations that mention an 'amount' field.  But doesn't the fact that the no-longer-used model (UnReimbursedExpenses, also with an 'amount' field) is appearing in the test db imply that the failure is in an earlier migration, before that model is removed?

The migrations is the culprit. You set the FloatField from default='' to no default to default=0.0.

@ChukwujiobiCanon  Yeah, I know, but if the original migrations passed, which they did, the unit test  should pass through those sequentially and use the most recent state of the db, and see my statement in the question that I did a recent migration to default='0.0' which resulted in the same error, because it's not getting to more recent states of the database.  To my knowledge, there's no way to remove early migrations while leaving later ones intact.

I think the answer might be to just do a reset of migrations, but retaining the data.  Unless someone comes up with a different solution.

Run showmigrations let’s know migration status.

@ChukwujiobiCanon  There are 76 of them, plus Django's own migrations, a lot to list here; but I can say that they all have '[x]' next to them.

A sneak peek will give me a better idea of what’s going on.

@Ron there's no way those migrations executed successfully. It is much more likely that you or someone from your team just faked the migration.

@Ron I don't see a need to "reset the migrations", why don't you just do what Chukwujiobi Canon mentions? Just edit the failing migration so that it doesn't fail anymore. Change default='' to default=0.0

The original question as posted is not about how to reset migrations, and NOT a duplicate of other SO questions on how to reset migrations.  It's about gaining deeper understanding of any underlying mechanisms which might allow the original migrations to execute flawlessly despite the errors in the code illustrated in the question, then fail in unit test.  All 76+ migrations in the history show up as successfully executed when listed by 'showmigrations', but now (properly) fail when a unit test database is generated.
The hope of the question is that a fix can be found without doing a migration reset.
It's as if data isn't applied to models defined in original migrations - as if model field definitions' word is taken for it - but then problems can still arise when actually instantiated in test.  However, I can't imagine that such a hole would exist in Django.  In any case, the scenario described in the question is a good argument for TDD.
Along the way, it was hoped that the nuances that can arise given the sequential, inter-dependent nature of migrations might be made clearer for any new Django users who might read this in the future, i.e. it's a little more complicated than 'just fix that one migration'.
But the bottom line is, whatever the underlying mechanisms or actions that led to the problem, the present action to be done is to execute a reset of migrations and generate a new initial migration.  The recommended method for doing that is at How to Reset Migrations .

Scenario 1 of this article describes exactly what you are being told here and is the recommended way of resetting your migrations by deleting the migrations folder. There is not a hole in Django, Django developers did not make an error. The migrations will continue to happen until you delete your migrations cache folder and regenerate the migrations folder. This is how Django works. If you are looking for a deeper understanding, I recommend you do some reading before you start posting bounties on Stack Overflow and answering yourself for points.

Maybe you should do some reading before you ask questions on stack overflow. We are here to help solve problems, not to argue semantics or have our insights nitpicked after we help you realize what the initial problem was and you decide to move on to the next problem. You have 27 questions and 7 answers. At some point you should start contributing to the public forum, especially if you are such an expert about this "hole" in Django nobody else ever realized.

The traceback shows this is happening when alter_field is called.
> line 235, in database_forwards
>     schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 830, in alter_field
>     self._alter_field(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py",
> line 287, in _alter_field
>     super()._alter_field(   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 1025, in _alter_field
>     new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 429, in effective_default
>     return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)   File
> "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
> line 954, in get_db_prep_save
>     return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)   File
> "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
> line 947, in get_db_prep_value
>     value = self.get_prep_value(value)   File "/var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
> line 1959, in get_prep_value
>     raise e.__class__( ValueError: Field 'amount' expected a number but got ''.

This is part of the initialization of the AlterField object. So the error isn't in your models.py. This is happening when you are trying to create the migrations.AlterField object.
Look here at the last line to see exactly what went wrong.
ValueError: Field 'amount' expected a number but got ''

So when you create a SQL database you need to have the type of the field match the data type you are trying to use. You gave the field 'amount' a default value in the database of a string when you created the AlterField object. But it is a FloatField, so we need to have a float.
This is the problematic code:
# Generated by Django 4.1.3 on 2023-01-10 22:58
from django.db import migrations, models   

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('giraffe', '0014_appointment_notes'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='appointment',
            name='amount',
            field=models.FloatField(blank=True, default=''),
        ),
    ]

The field 'amount' is being given a empty string '' for default, just like the error says. We need a float.
# Generated by Django 4.1.3 on 2023-01-10 22:58
from django.db import migrations, models   

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('giraffe', '0014_appointment_notes'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='appointment',
            name='amount',
            field=models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0.0),
        ),
    ]

Likewise, all your FloatField objects need to have a default float value when they are created. The very next migration after 0014_appointment_notes, 0015_alter_appointment_amount does not have any default value for FloatField. Change it to have a default float value.
The changed code:
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
dependencies = [
    ('giraffe', '0015_alter_appointment_amount'),
]
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='appointment',
        name='amount',
        field=models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0.0),
    ),
]

You may have tried to change this and nothing happened.
As Ron said in the comment section, the solution is to reset your migrations. That may be tricky for you if you aren't familiar with how migrations work in Django. There is a hidden folder in each folder where you have a Django application, that is each folder that has its own models.py. This is a cache file that is created after makemigrations is called in order to speed up the migrate command because usually the models themselves are not changed. Adding a new model will update this cache, but changing one will not. Make sure you delete each hidden folder .migrations as well as all the files and folders within using the Unix command.
rm -r .migrations

Running the migrate command will now automatically run the command makemigrations as the .migrations folder does not exist and now has to be created in order to migrate the database.
Previous models you tried to delete will no longer be present when you migrate the database as long as you make sure that you are migrating to a fresh database that does not already have that previous model written to it.

a) Agreed that these are the problems, but the question remains:  how did these migrations successfully execute when originally generated?  b) Yes, resetting migrations is dicey, but Victor Freitas explains it elegantly.

There's no need to delete all the migrations plus the database just for one failing migration. The failing migration(s) can easily be deleted or fixed. As a general note too many people keep recommending to simply delete the migrations + DB, which is in fact the real cause of people getting stuck with a weird migration history compared to the real database state, please avoid giving such recommendations.

@Ron A) As I explained these migrations were generated because they were in the cache file in the folder ".migrations". You have to delete this folder or you are going to keep doing the same migrations. Its not dicey, I just explained to you how to reset your migrations. If you didn't need an answer and you can understand it from an article than there is no reason to set a bounty for a question.

Furthermore, Im not really sure that @Abdul understands what is going on with Django/SQL. The idea is to use Django to generate a perfect SQL table and forgo using SQL manually. The problem only arises when you delete your database and start over without deleting your cache files. If you delete your cache files in ".migrations" then there is nothing for the migrations to go off of and they have to be completely regenerated using the code. This should be understood by junior Django developers and contributors on this forum.

Essentially, this is a basic topic that you can read about. Instead of arguing semantics, lets just find a way to reset our migrations and close this topic. This post is being flagged as a duplicate of an existing post. Please refer to existing information such as this post's top comment which iterates what I said but does not tell the junior programmer anything about the "migrations" folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253399/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-1-7

One should note that, in production you may need to add/delete sections of your table to extend functionality and scope. In development, we generate the tables using Django. It is not recommended to start with malformed and edited databases. A fresh production server should have a perfect SQL table that can be added on to later or changed only if need be. In development, delete the database and make sure you are generating a perfect table. That is my opinion as a developer, and it is up to your discretion to do what you choose.
